# Mysql query Last Updated Row

Tags: mysql

I have data in my database

```
ID    UserID   CourseName   Grade                                  
 1      8        CourseA      75
 2      8        CourseA      102 
 3      8        CourseA      115
 4      8        CourseA      111
 5      8        CourseA      112
 6      8        CourseB      60
 7      8        CourseB      45
 8      8        CourseB      58
 9      8        CourseB      60
 10     8        CourseB      74
 11     8        CourseC      130
 12     8        CourseC      140
 13     8        CourseC      133 
 14     8        CourseC      135
```

I need the last updated grade for a single course like

```
`8     CourseA   112    
 8     CourseB   74
 8     CourseC   135`
```

Could anyone suggest me an sql query for this.

Comment: Without another column like an incrementing id or timestamp, you _cannot_ get the last one reliably since there is no deterministic order here. Are these all the columns in your table or are there more?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, updating my answer:

Got it:

```
SELECT UserID, CourseName, Grade
FROM yourtable
WHERE UserID = '8'
AND ID
IN (
    SELECT MAX( ID ) 
    FROM yourtable
    GROUP BY CourseName
)
```

Comment: Can you please post the structure of your table?

Comment: Its a big table with lots of columns

Comment: Thank You for your suggestion, but iam getting only one row i.e., for Course C. I need for 3 Courses

Answer (score 0):

You can add another column 
modified date

```
alter table tableName add column modifiedDate DEFAULT NOW() ON UPDATE NOW()
```

then you get the last updated grade for course

```
 select * from tableName where course ='CourseA' 
 order by modifiedDate desc limit 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from Course a 
where id=(select max(b.id) from Course b where b.CourseName=a.CourseName);
```

Aftwerwards you can group your result by ID, CourseName

Not tested!

Answer (score 0):

SELECT * FROM  Table ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1;